# Exposed Dropdown Menus - with no filter from xml resource

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-xml, android-databinding

### Context

When you use the following object: `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` or `AutoCompleteTextView` you can specify if the text filter the result or not. You can do this using the method [setText(CharSequence text, boolean filter)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20boolean)) and i quote:

> boolean: If false, no filtering will be performed as a result of this
> call.

.. and the method works perfectly!

### The question

**Is it possible to do the same thing directly from xml?** Let me explain, using the [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) I am able to set a value via the `android:text` xml attribute. Like this:

```
<MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
    android:text="@{viewmodel.data}" />
```

Since I don't have the option to specify whether I actually want to filter the results or not, it uses the default setting which is true.. unfortunately for me I would like to use false.

### More info

I did some research using the official documentation but found nothing in the pages that reference the [MaterialAutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/MaterialAutoCompleteTextView) and [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create an `BindingAdapter` and set those values using `Databinding` without no issues at all.

For example, you could create something like:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:text", "app:filter")
fun MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.updateFilter(text: String, filter: Boolean) {
    this.setText(text, filter)
}
```

And then, use `databinding` in your xml as:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:filter="@{ here comes filter value }"
    app:text="@{ here comes text value }" />
```

Keep in mind that I didn't run this code so there may be some typo issues, but I guess you get the idea.
Another thing to consider is in `Kotlin` code I used an extension function, you can easily change that and pass `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` as first parameter.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

### How I've implemented:

Following hardartcore answer, I've look into [binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) and their best practice. Inside my model class I've added a method that has been referenced for actualy binding the data using the function I've defined.

```
public class Model {
    ...

    @BindingAdapter(value = {"text", "filter"})
    public static void setText(MaterialAutoCompleteTextView view, String text, Boolean filter) {
        view.setText(text, filter);
    }
}
```

`value` specify the arguments that are needed to use your function, you can also use `requiredAll = false` to tell that maybe there will be some `null` values. In my case i always need both so inside the xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
    ...

    app:filter="@{false}"
    app:text="@{mode.variable}" />
```